# What environment variables should I track to explain a 10 minutes difference on a timestamp sent by a front application and received by a backend one?

Tags: timestamps, timezone

Two *Linux* computers, I'm not knowing yet their exact settings, are running:

- A front application, for the first
- A backend application, for the second

I face the trouble that what the backend receives, for timestamp, has **10 minutes less** than what the user typed in his form and submitted.

Example: `1908-08-08T11:12:39.000Z` when the user typed `11 h 22`

I've searched on the system initialization scripts but found nothing immediately related to some timezone settings. But something must be set somewhere about time management, that cause this difference.

What *Linux* environnement variables should I track, on both systems, to try to explain that strange behavior?

Comment: A bug on the application?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It's not impossible... But what would I respond to someone who would tell me "_Aren't you sure that this can't be caused by some Linux settings?_". I have to check first, and I don't know what I should check for that. Does a way exist, somewhere, on Linux system, to change the timezone of it causing a delta of few minutes only? Afghanistan and North Korea have 30 minutes deltas and not only plain hours, for example.

Comment: It'd be an extremely weird timezone setting that would cause a 10-minute offset. But there are only limited places for that - the `TZ` environment variable, `/etc/localtime` off the top of my head. I'd suspect the app before those.

Comment: Could you check that both computers have the same time? Some upgrades may have broken network timekeeping. But usually the best way it is to log string exiting of system 1 and log also what enter in machine 2. So you can also know if it is software, or machine 1 or machine 2 error

Comment: I had some issues already for keeping time accurate on VM's on Hyper-V. NTP wasn't enough so I had to disable it and use ntpdate each mn in cron because the VM derived by around 15mn / day. It only happens on Hyper-V !

Comment: `date` on either or both systems would be a good start. Is the date/time correct? What about the timezone offset from UTC (`date --utc`). Notice in your example datetime string the year is 1908. This strongly suggests it's simply that the date/time is wrong

Comment: @ChrisDavies Good idea, the two `date` commands. The 1908 is what was really typed. The problem is in the hours, minutes. But like you all, I'm now nearer a software bug than a problem in OS settings.